# Classe derivada da classe PrintDocument C#

Tags: c#, classes, impressão

Tenho uma classe para imprimir etiquetas (CPrint), essa classe é derivada da classe `PrintDocument`. Nela recebe uma imagem chamando um método contido na classe `Form1.cs`.

Segue o código da classe `CPrint.cs` (derivada da classe `PrintDocument`):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
class CPrint : PrintDocument
{
    private Font printFont;
    private TextReader printStream;
    private string fileToPrint;
    private Bitmap imgWatermark, bmpImg;

    public bool Watermark = false;

    public CPrint()
    {
        Form1 principal = new Form1();

        imgWatermark = principal.enviaImg();  //ESSE TEM QUE RECEBER A IMAGEM


    }

    public CPrint(string fileName) : this()
    {
        this.FileToPrint = fileName;
    }

    public string FileToPrint
    {
        get
        {
            return fileToPrint;
        }
        set
        {
            if (File.Exists(value))
            {
                CPrint p = new CPrint();
                fileToPrint = value;
                this.DocumentName = value;
            }
            else
                throw (new Exception("File not found."));
        }
    }

    public Font Font
    {
        get { return printFont; }
        set { printFont = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnBeginPrint(PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBeginPrint(e);
        printFont = new Font("Verdana", 10);
        printStream = new StreamReader(FileToPrint);
    }

    protected override void OnEndPrint(PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnEndPrint(e);
        printFont.Dispose();
        printStream.Close();
    }

    protected override void OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPrintPage(e);

        // Slow down printing for demo.
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);

        Graphics gdiPage = e.Graphics;
        float leftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
        float topMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
        float lineHeight = printFont.GetHeight(gdiPage);
        float linesPerPage = e.MarginBounds.Height / lineHeight;
        int lineCount = 0;
        string lineText = null;

        // Watermark?
        if (this.Watermark)
        {
            int top = Math.Max(0,
                     (e.PageBounds.Height - imgWatermark.Height) / 2);
            int left = Math.Max(0,
                     (e.PageBounds.Width - imgWatermark.Width) / 2);
            gdiPage.DrawImage(imgWatermark, left, top,
                     imgWatermark.Width, imgWatermark.Height);
        }

        // Print each line of the file.
        while (lineCount < linesPerPage &&
              ((lineText = printStream.ReadLine()) != null))
        {
            gdiPage.DrawString(lineText, printFont, Brushes.Black,
            leftMargin, (topMargin + (lineCount++ * lineHeight)));
        }

        // If more lines exist, print another page.
        if (lineText != null)
            e.HasMorePages = true;
        else
            e.HasMorePages = false;
    }
}
}
```

O que está dando errado é que o nome do documento que não é adquirido e com isso no método `OnBeginPrint` nesta linha `printStream = new StreamReader(FileToPrint);` não recebe o retorno do método `FileToPrint` porque ele (método `FileToPrint`) só executa a parte `get` do código e não o `set` que onde deveria adquirir o nome do arquivo.

Desde já agradecida!

Comment: Quem escreveu essa classe `PrintDocument`?

Comment: A classe `PrintDocument` é do próprio C# para impressão.

Comment: @kaamis aplicação desktop ou web ? e descreva objetivamente qual funcionalidade você quer realizar no click desse botão !?

Comment: @ThiagoFalcão é desktop. Quero que quando o botão é clicado apareça a caixa de diálogo de impressão do Windows e realize uma impressão a partir da classe CPrint derivada da PrintDocument. Contudo, consegui achar um código para chamar a classe, que é bem simples afinal, o meu problema agora é que não imprime pois o nome do documento não é adquirido pelo método FileToPrint. Irei até editar a pergunta.

Comment: Cole aqui o código que você usa para invocar a impressão.

Comment: @FernandoNomellini segue o código que está num botão para invocar a impressão:
`CPrint printDoc = new CPrint();
            PrintDialog dlgPrint = new PrintDialog();

            dlgPrint.Document = printDoc;

            if (dlgPrint.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                printDoc.Print();
            }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que você está usando o construtor errado.

Seu código do botão.

```
Print printDoc = new CPrint(); 
rintDialog dlgPrint = new PrintDialog(); 
lgPrint.Document = printDoc; 
f (dlgPrint.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { printDoc.Print(); }
```

Você não acha que deveria ser usado este :

```
Print printDoc = new CPrint("NomeDoDocumentoASerImpresso");
```

Pois é o construtor que recebe o nome do documento e associa à propriedade privada `fileToPrint`

Comment: Entendi o que quis dizer, eu tenho que enviar a imagem também pois é ela que vai ser impressa. Ou só com o nome do bitmap gerado eu já consigo fazer isso? Poderia deixar o construtor que está e adicionar este que você falou? Um para chamar e receber a imagem e outro com o nome do documento?

Comment: Kaamis, você precisa imprimir um determinado arquivo, e junto com ele, a imagem, correto ? Tente alterar o programa usando o codigo que eu te passei. Troca apenas a linha que eu indiquei passando o nome de um arquivo. veja se funciona. Pelo que eu vi, a imagem já será carregada mesmo usando o construtor que recebe o nome do arquivo.

Comment: Na verdade preciso imprimir somente a imagem. Desculpe a ignorância mas como posso obter o nome da imagem gerada? Ou seria o nome da variável bitmap?

Comment: tem algumas formas, como esta: FileStream fs = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName , FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
dê uma olhada: http://www.macoratti.net/09/09/c_prn1.htm

Comment: @FernandoNomellini eu salvei a imagem e peguei o nome dela. Enfim deu certo mas, depois veio outro erro e descobri que a classe derivada não dava para imprimir imagens. Aí resolvi ao invés de gerar uma imagem gerar um arquivo texto, porque eu quero imprimir etiquetas que contenham códigos de barras, e consegui usar uma fonte específica. Assim deu certo. Muito obrigada pela ajuda!